# QGIS not showing the course of the line with arrow symbol and 'arrow at each segment' unchecked

Tags: qgis, symbology, line

I want QGIS to show arrow at the end of each line but not at each segment on the line. When I select arrow symbol and uncheck repeat arrow at each segment, it draw a straight line from beginning point to the endpoint, without following the course of the line. How to fix this to get the course of the line and also the arrow at the end of the line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create an arrow with only one arrowhead at the end of the line you need to create two layers-symbology: a simple line and a marker line as you can see below

[image]

The arrowhead is a marker line type which is a tree of symbols. Here, you can choose whether you want to place the arrowhead at each vertex or only the last vertex or any other place.

[image]

Then change the marker from circle to triangle and add an offset if necessary.

[image]

Regarding the simple line, it is just a line you add it at the bottom of the arrow head using the Plus button.

[image]

Here is the final output:

[image]

Comment: Excelent solution!!! Thanks. I used a Marker Line with SVG Marker....Even better.